# What is the best way to compare 35 availability timeslots between two parties?

Tags: database, ruby-on-rails-4, data-structures, matching

This is for a ruby app, but the problem is more general.

Party 1 requires party 2 to be available for work, however rather than specific timing, it is more general

Monday to Sunday

Morning
Afternoon
Evening
Overnight
Overnight- awake

In other words  7 days with 5 time slots, creating 35 matching points

The simplest way would be to add 35 columns, with Boolean for both parties and then see if the respective columns match. We can measure the degree to which they match via a count.

Given this needs  to be done multiple times, party 1 required availability against  hundreds, possibly thousands of party 2 offered availablity I'm concerned that this will be very slow.

1. I would appreciate opinions on the above approach to the problem
2. is there a better way to store this matrix/array of required/availability that would make the compare faster?
3. any thoughts where this calculation should happen, dB or controller, helper?

Comment: Would you rather do this entirely in SQL or woild

Comment: Would you rather do this entirely in SQL or would you be able to do it in-memory instead? Also, are you sure the requirements are static? What if the time slots change and you need 40 or 50 time slots per day?

Comment: No the timeslots are static, there will be a more detailed discussion at later stage but the overall slots are fixed. I'm open to a solution at the dB level or memory in the app, the question is really which approach  and data structure is most efficient?